# Express checkout braintree sdk

Tags: android

Express checkout braintree sdk does not pay or get amount from user logged in with paypal. The token is got successfully from server and we can go to express checkout sdk, but the amount does not reflect at the top as usually does before user pays, and when a user logs in and clicks continue it just closes and does not charge the client the amount.Any help please

Comment: Found an answer

Comment: found an answer